# What does $\Gamma$ notation (as in "$A=\Gamma(x_1)$" for a vertex $x_1$) mean in graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, notation

I was looking at a proof for

> Let $G$ be a connected graph of order $n$ and $\delta(G) \geq k/2$ for some integer $k < n$. Then $G$ contains a simple path of length $k$.

which is Lemma 4 (page 4) in Heng Guo's lecture notes ["Forbidden Paths and Cycles" (PDF link via ed.ac.uk)](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/hguo/files/16.fall-adv.comb/Lecture_2_03.10.2016.pdf). I was confused by this notation:

> ... Since $P$ is a maximal path, the neighbours of $x_0$ and $x_\ell$ must be all inside $P$. Let
> $$A = \Gamma(x_1), \quad B = \{x_{i+1} : x_i \in \Gamma(x_\ell)\}$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In **graph theory** some authors use $\Gamma(x)$ for the set of all neighbors of the vertex $x$.

Comment: Thankyou, that makes so much sense!

Comment: In Definition 7 (page 3) of [the author's notes for Lecture 1](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/hguo/files/16.fall-adv.comb/Lecture_1_26.09.2016.pdf), $\Gamma(v)$ is defined as the neighbourhood of vertex $v$: $$\Gamma(v) = \{u\; |\; u \in V(G), (u,v)\in E(G)\} $$